# I want to hide previous if else condition when new condition appears. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to hide previous marker appears through if else condition when new marker appears.

```js
                
if(curTime >= 0 && curTime <=1){
  L.marker([51.5, -0.08], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
} else if(curTime >=2 && curTime <=3) {
  L.marker([51.5, -0.079], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
} else if(curTime >=3 && curTime <=4) {
  L.marker([51.5, -0.078], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
} else if(curTime >=4 && curTime <=5) {
  L.marker([51.5, -0.077], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
} else if(curTime >=5 && curTime <=6) {
  L.marker([51.5, -0.076], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
} else if(curTime >=6 && curTime <=7) {
  L.marker([51.5, -0.075], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: You can't hide JS code. Can you please elaborate what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I making a code to change the marker location and it is working perfectly but when the new marker appears the older one overlaps it. I want to hide older marker when new marker appears on map.

Comment: add a new method to remove the previous marker before adding new one.

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh can you suggest me something, what can I do?

Comment: show how your addTo(map) function is working.

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh ```var map = L.map('map').setView([51.5, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
 attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
}).addTo(map);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the markers to a `L.FeatureGroup` and remove then with `clearLayers()` all markers from the featureGroup / map, before you add a new one.

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map); // this is a global variable, don't add it to the function where you add the markers.


fucntion XYTest(){ // Your function where you add the markers
  var curTime = ...
  ...
  ...

  fg.clearLayers();
  if(curTime >= 0 && curTime <=1){
    L.marker([51.5, -0.08], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(fg);
  } else if(curTime >=2 && curTime <=3) {
    L.marker([51.5, -0.079], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(fg);
  } else if(curTime >=3 && curTime <=4) {
    L.marker([51.5, -0.078], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(fg);
  } else if(curTime >=4 && curTime <=5) {
    L.marker([51.5, -0.077], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(fg);
  } else if(curTime >=5 && curTime <=6) {
    L.marker([51.5, -0.076], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(fg);
  } else if(curTime >=6 && curTime <=7) {
    L.marker([51.5, -0.075], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(fg);
  }
}
```

**OR**

You can only change the position of the marker instead of creating a new one.

```
var marker = L.marker([]).addTo(map); // global marker variable


fucntion XYTest(){ // Your function where you add the markers
  var curTime = ...
  ...
  ...

  if(curTime >= 0 && curTime <=1){
    marker.setLatLng([51.5, -0.08]);
  } else if(curTime >=2 && curTime <=3) {
    marker.setLatLng([51.5, -0.079]);
  } else if(curTime >=3 && curTime <=4) {
    marker.setLatLng([51.5, -0.078]);
  } else if(curTime >=4 && curTime <=5) {
    marker.setLatLng([51.5, -0.077]);
  } else if(curTime >=5 && curTime <=6) {
    marker.setLatLng([51.5, -0.076]);
  } else if(curTime >=6 && curTime <=7) {
    marker.setLatLng([51.5, -0.075]);
  }
}
```